# Cannot manually stretch a draggable div

Tags: javascript, html

I created a draggable div :

```js
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "Header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "Header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV: 
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}

dragElement(document.getElementById("infoVehicule"));
```

```html
<div id="infoVehicule">
  <div id="infoVehiculeHeader"></div>
  <p id="infoVehiculeContent"></p>
  <p id="infoVehiculeTrajets"></p>
</div>
```

At runtime I cannot stretch it to enlarge manually its width. So how to make it possible to stretch this div to enlarge its width manually ?

Comment: A div is `display:block` by default. Which means its width is 100%, so it's difficult to make it even larger. If you want it to fit its content, use `display:inline-block`, so you can then enlarge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jqueryui resizable plugin to enlarge width of div manually

for better understanding attaching jsfiddle